# What do you call these flowering vaults, gates?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a particular word used to refer to them?

Comment: Most commonly the thing in the picture is called an 'arch of flowers' or 'flower arch'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are often called **floral arches**:

- [17 Epic Floral Arches and How to Get One](https://onefabday.com/epic-floral-arches/)
- [10 Darling Floral Arches for Your Wedding Ceremony](https://www.mywedding.com/wedding-ideas/10-darling-floral-arches-for-your-wedding-ceremony/)
- [The 3 Things You Need to Know About Floral Arches for Your Wedding](https://blovedblog.com/weddings/3-things-need-know-floral-arches-wedding/)

Also **flower arch** is used.

Answer (score 1):

"Arbor" and "pergola" are terms for these types of structure. There are many web pages giving further information. One view is that an arbor has two or four legs (the vertical part touching the ground) whereas a pergola has four or more verticals. However many people assume the words are synonyms.